# I want my query to treat the content of two columns as one

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of news articles. These have both `tags` and `articleTags`.
Our API has a endpoint that returns articles that matches all tags. 
E.g. searching for an article that contains both `sport` and `fail`:

```
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tags": "sport"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "tags": "fail"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "articleTags": "sport"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "articleTags": "fail"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
```

This worked when we only had `tags`, but when we introduced `articleTags` then it obviously didn't work as expected.

Is there a way we could make Elasticsearch treat `tags` and `articleTags` as 
one namespace so I could do a query like this?

```
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "mergedTags": "sport"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "mergedTags": "fail"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
```

Comment: Use `copy_to` functionality to achieve this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-all.html#custom-all. Meaning creating a new field `mergedTags` and `articleTags` and `tags` should use `"copy_to": "mergedTags"`. Then use `mergedTags` in your query instead of `tags` and `articleTags`.

Answer (score 1):

I feel [multi match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query would be the best solution here.

There is a type of multi match query which is called cross_fields . 
And its function as told by the documentation is

```
Treats fields with the same analyzer as though they were one big field. Looks for each word in any field. See cross_fields.
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion involves using `copy_to` to create that "merged" field:

```
    "tags": {
      "type": "string",
      "copy_to": "mergedTags"
    },
    "articleTags": {
      "type": "string",
      "copy_to": "mergedTags"
    },
    "mergedTags": {
      "type": "string"
    }
```

And the updated query is a simple as:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        [
          {
            "term": {
              "mergedTags": "sport"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "mergedTags": "fail"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
```